# Complex euclidean tensor products

Tags: tensor-products, inner-products

Say you have Euclidean vectors $\mathbf{a}=a_i \mathbf{p}_i$ and $\mathbf{b}=b_j \mathbf{q}_j$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with bases $\mathbf{p}_i$ and $\mathbf{q}_j$. Then you could use a typical inner product to find $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}=a_i b_j (\mathbf{p}_i \cdot \mathbf{q}_j)=a_i b_j g_{ij}^{pq}$, where $g_{ij}^{pq}$ is a metric between the two bases.  You can also perform a tensor product $\mathbf{a}\otimes\mathbf{b}=a_i b_j (\mathbf{p}_i \otimes \mathbf{q}_j)$, where for $\mathbf{c}=c_k \mathbf{r}_k$, we have products of vectors with tensors $(\mathbf{a}\otimes\mathbf{b})\cdot\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{a}(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c})$ and $\mathbf{c}\cdot(\mathbf{a}\otimes\mathbf{b})=(\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{a})\mathbf{b}$.

Now say $\mathbf{p}_i=\mathbf{q}_i=\mathbf{r}_i=\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i$, where $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i$ are the standard Cartesian unit vectors.  Everything is unchanged, although $g_{ij}^{pq}$ becomes $\delta_{ij}$.  For the moment, I’m not going to worry about defining co- or contra-variant bases and the details of their inner products.

That’s great.  But what happens when we look now at $\mathbb{C}^3$, in the general case that both the scalar components and the bases can be complex.  I’m fine with defining the inner product to include a complex conjugate (in either the first or second term), e.g. $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}=\overline{a}_i b_j (\mathbf{p}_i \cdot \mathbf{q}_j)=\overline{a}_i b_j g_{ij}^{pq}$.  This means that now $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}=\overline{\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{a}}$.

But here I start to get myself confused.  Texts often define the tensor (outer) product to include a conjugate on the side opposing the inner product, e.g. $\mathbf{a}\otimes\mathbf{b}=a_i \overline{b}_j (\mathbf{p}_i \otimes \mathbf{q}_j)$ to match the inner product defined above.  Which leads me to several interrelated questions:

1. Is this conjugate in the outer product necessary, and how does this affect $(\mathbf{a}\otimes\mathbf{b})\cdot\mathbf{c}=[a_i \overline{b}_j (\mathbf{p}_i \otimes \mathbf{q}_j)]\cdot(c_k \mathbf{r}_k)$ and similar vector/tensor products?
2. How does this affect tensors of higher order, such as $\mathbf{a}\otimes\mathbf{b}\otimes\mathbf{c}$?  Does $(\mathbf{a}\otimes\mathbf{b})\otimes\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{a}\otimes(\mathbf{b}\otimes\mathbf{c})$?
3. Is there a need to use complex conjugate basis vectors (i.e. dual spaces) such as $\overline{\mathbf{p}}_i$?  If the bases were all Cartesian $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i$ bases, would there be a need to keep track of something like $\overline{\hat{\mathbf{e}}}_i$, or would this be identical to $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i$?

I’ve been pondering this for a while, but haven’t found quite the right references to figure it out.  Any pointers would be great!

Edit: As commented below, this might be a bit of an overly broad question. Really, the question about whether a complex conjugate would be required for such outer products (#1) is the most critical.

Comment: You are asking three very broad questions in a single question, and so you are likely to get little attention and probably only partial responses. You ought to focus on your main question and try to build the others as follow-ups.

Comment: " Texts often define the tensor (outer) product to include a conjugate on the side opposing the inner product" I've never seen a text do this, but it sounds interesting. Could you say where you saw this?

Comment: To be fair, I've very commonly seen the use of similar complex conjugates in linear algebra and physics (bra-ket notation), not in the exact situation in my question.  There is a thesis named "Towards a covariant formulation of electromagnetic wave polarization" online from Olofsson that also uses it in this way (see eq. 2.74).  But the best reference I've found, "Plasticity: A Treatise on Finite Deformation of Heterogeneous Inelastic Materials" by Nemat-Nasser (section 1.1.2), does not use a complex conjugate, and seems to restrict to real bases.